# Datatables plugin for jQuery. How to hide rows? Export to Excel still showing hidden rows

Tags: datatables

I was able to figure out how to hide the rows I wanted using JQuery. I have a modal that pops out for the user deselects the checkbox on what rows they want to hide. It works perfectly but when I export it to excel it still displays the hidden rows. I am not using the API at all and I think that's my problem. I am hiding the rows by using `.show()` and `.hide()`. I am using the API to hide the columns and when I click my export to excel button it works just fine. Could anyone help me figure out how to hide rows and be able to export it to excel with the rows not showing on the spreadsheet?

**HTML**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js">
</script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" class="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Store 1</th>
            <th>Store 2</th>
            <th>Store 3</th>
            <th>Store 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Sugar</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Coffee</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Banana</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>323</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>233</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gum</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>213</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Milk</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>44</td>
            <td>242</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

        </div>
    </body>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
 var table = $('.example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                },
                text: 'Export to Excel'
            },
        ],

    });
    // I get the attribute name from the checkbox and I match it with the id on the row and when the checkbox is unchecked I hide the rows.
    $('input.rowsHideSeek').click(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#' + name).show()

        } else {
            $('#' + name).hide()

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and it seems to work.   It shows and hides rows and, on export, only shows rows not hidden.

here is it is on jsbin http://jsbin.com/qituvu/edit?output

The key part is that it uses the customizeData in the extended excelHtml5.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // this just creates a critera to filter on
        var faketype = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < dataStore.data1.length; ++i) {
            dataStore.data1[i].type = faketype++;
            if (faketype == 5) faketype = 1;
        }
        var aTable = $('#example').DataTable({
            "data": dataStore.data1,
            paging:false,
            "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office", className: "editColumn" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" },
            { "data": "type"}
            ], dom: 'Bfrti',
            "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
                $(row).addClass('type_' + data.type);
            },
            buttons: [{text:"Excel",
                extend: 'excelHtml5', customizeData: function (exData) {
                    var rowNodes = aTable.rows().nodes();
                    var newData = []
                    for (var i = (exData.body.length - 1) ; i >= 0; i--) {

                        if ($(rowNodes[i]).css("display") == "none") {
                            continue;
                        }
                        newData[newData.length] = exData.body[i];

                    }
                    // the loop reverses order so put it back
                    exData.body = newData.reverse();

                }}]
        });

        // event handler for hiding and showing rows
        $("input[name='hideType']").on("click", function () {
            var c = $(this).val();
            var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
            $(aTable.rows('.type_' + c).nodes()).toggle(isChecked);
            aTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with jQuery `hide()` / `show()` is that you will need to tweak any part of dataTables you are using, if you want to fake persistent "hidden" rows.

Here is a few plug-in methods that provide **real** `hide()` and `restore()` on rows in dataTables :

```js
$.fn.dataTableExt.hiddenRows = {};

$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'row.hide()', function(selector) {
  var row = this.row(selector);
  if (row.length == 0) return -1;
  var index = row.node()._DT_RowIndex;
  $.fn.dataTableExt.hiddenRows[index] = row.node().outerHTML;  
  row.remove().draw(false);
  return index;
});

$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'row.restore()', function(index) {
   var row = $.fn.dataTableExt.hiddenRows[index];
   if (row) {
     this.row.add( $(row) ).draw(false);
     delete $.fn.dataTableExt.hiddenRows[index];
     return true;
   }
   return false;
});
```

Now you have `table.row.hide()` and `table.row.restore()`. The methods use the dataTables API, and does nothing but maintaining a list of removed rows by their unique indexes. A demo could look like this :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({}) ;

$('#example').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
  var index = table.row.hide(this);
  var $button = $('<button></button>')
    .addClass('restore')
    .attr('index', index)
    .text('show #'+index);
  $('body').prepend($button);
})

$('body').on('click', '.restore', function() {
  var index = $(this).attr('index');
  table.row.restore(index);
  $(this).remove();
})
```

When you click on a row it is hidden (i.e removed); a restore button is generated for each hidden row. If you click on the button the corresponding row is restored.

Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s183ek2q/**